# My VueJS devtools do not show for some webpages, but it does for others. Why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have installed the `vue js` extension and for some other pages I created, it works
But for my current website, it does not show on the inspect elements tab, although the vue js still runs successfully

If needed, here is my html and js for the website in which the devtools does not show

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->  
  </head>
  <body class="container mt-4">
    <div id="app">
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Kinda cryptic with just this info. Are we speaking local dev websites or hosted ones (in production)? Also, did you tried toggling the devtools back and forth? Which devtools are you running, the one for Vue2 or Vue3? Can you see the Vue app with this extension? https://vuetelescope.com/ (Or with wappalyzer)

Comment: @kissu I'm using vue js v2 and the version of the devtool is 6.1.4. This is my first time asking a question on stack overflow, so sorry if there are any misunderstandings or anything

Comment: Working totally fine on my side. Do you serve the thing with a server (like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve))? You cannot just open the `index.html`.

Comment: @kissu I just opened the file in google chrome

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory with your `index.html` + JS files, then run [`npx serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) and you'll see the devtools pop.

You need to run a lightweight server to serve the files properly, this simple solution will do the job and display the devtools accordingly.

Also, try to toggle your devtools (hide and show them back).
Or kill and bring back the tab again, sometimes it needs it.

Comment: My issue was resolved, I just needed to enable the "Allow Access To File URL's" property in my vue js extension. Thanks for the help though !

Comment: @user18800522 you should not need that if you run a server AFAIK.

Comment: @user18800522 It is interesting for me to know that if you had not enabled that before, So how it works for **some other pages** in your app?

Comment: Good question, in truth, not exactly sure myself. But when I said other pages I mean separate projects that I created. I tested some of them and it seems that that option does not have to be enabled for pages that are hosted on localhost (the projects afore mentioned were) to actually make the tool available for those pages. Sorry for the confusion